# Error "render is a Node specific API" when using the module @react-pdf/renderer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf, pdf-generation, react-pdf

Using the module `@react-pdf/renderer` with official example (https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/@react-pdf/renderer):

```
    import ReactPDF, { Document, Page, Text, View, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

    // Create styles
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        page: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4'
        },
        section: {
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
        flexGrow: 1
        }
    });
    
    // Create Document Component
    const MyDocument = (): JSX.Element => (
        <Document>
            <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text>Section #1</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text>Section #2</Text>
                </View>
            </Page>
        </Document>
    );

    ReactPDF.render(<MyDocument />, `example.pdf`);
```

But I get an error:

> Error: render is a Node specific API. You're either using this method
> in a browser, or your bundler is not loading react-pdf from the
> appropriate web build.

Please tell me why this error occurred and how I can fix it

Comment: I had the same problem here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The render function only works on the server and react works on the client side, if you want to render in the browser then check the ReactDOM.render function makes use of PDFViewer component.

Answer (score 3):

if you're using Next.js, dynamically import your PDF template with ssr option set to false

```
    const Template = dynamic(() => import("@/componants/Templates/PDF/Formation"), {
          loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
          ssr: false,
          });
```